# What's the point of omitting the "e", as in "sceptered" going to "scepter'd", in English poetry?

Tags: poetry, orthography

These are a few of my favorite lines of Shakespearean poetry:

> Methinks I am a prophet new **inspir’d**,
>   And thus expiring do foretell of him:
>   His rash fierce blaze of riot cannot last,
>   For violent fires soon burn out themselves;
>   Small showers last long, but sudden storms are short;
>   He tires betimes that spurs too fast betimes;
>   With eager feeding food doth choke the feeder:
>   Light vanity, insatiate cormorant,
>   Consuming means, soon preys upon itself.
>
> This royal throne of kings, this **scepter’d** isle,
>   This earth of majesty, this seat of Mars,
>   This other Eden, demi-paradise,
>   This fortress built by Nature for herself
>   Against infection and the hand of war,
>   This happy breed of men, this little world,
>   This precious stone set in the silver sea,
>   Which serves it in the office of a wall,
>   Or as a moat defensive to a house,
>   Against the envy of less happier lands,
>   This blessed plot, this earth, this realm, this England.

What I don't understand, though, is the removal of the 'e' by Shakespeare, and other poets who do this, like Tennyson.  I've always read diacritics are applied by some poets to change the pronunciation, so as to keep the meter, but how on Earth is *inspired* pronounced differently from *inspir'd*, or *sceptered* from *scepter'd*?  Why are they doing this?

Comment: Didn't a lot of the words in Shakespearean English have a separate syllable for the "-ed"? For example, "interred" was pronounced "in-ter-ed". I don't know much about this though, just wondering. This would have to imply that "inspired" was pronounced "in-spy-red" which seems odd.

Comment: From all I've come to understand, that "oddity" was the norm.  The -tion ending also appears to have been pronounced "tee-an".

Comment: Shakespeare suffered from chronic, periodic hick-ups.  These are merely places where his hand moved from a hick, while writing the manuscript. (Actually, it should be "up-I-hick", to be grammatically correct.)  Don't forget this *is* the guy who can't pronounce a name consistently, to keep his rhyme. (Rosoline -> "Ros-o-lioned")

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was to signify that the syllable was omitted. In most cases today, we don't pronounce the final syllable in many *-ed* endings that used to always be articulated. You can see a remnant of this in the word *learned*: We say that word in one syllable in the sentence

> I learned a lot from him.

but pronounce it as two syllables in

> He was a very learned individual.

The idea of the apostrophe was to show that the syllable was being left out so that the line would scan correctly. In the first line of your example, pronouncing the final syllable *-ed* *inspired* would ruin the iambic pentameter and leave the last syllable unstressed.

At one time, *inspired* would have been pronounced as in•spi•red, and *sceptered* would have been scep•ter•ed. Shakespeare, Tennyson, and other poets were just making sure their verses would scan for the reader.

Comment: And as late as the mid-Nineteenth Century, dropping the "e" would have been considered a little *déclassé* in "proper" society. English has always been going to the dogs.

Comment: Are you sure about that, Stan? My impression was that when Tennyson writes it it's an archaism.

Comment: Is "wicked" also an example of the old pronunciation being used in modern English?

Comment: @Giorgio; that's a very good question.  *Wick-ed* is not a participle: it's an adjective.  *Wicked* (one syllable) is the past participle (or past tense) of the verb 'to wick', which was not uncommon until the 19th century (all those candles), but fell out of use until recently, when it was revived by the makers of outdoor clothing.

Comment: @TimLymington: So, if I understand correctly, there is a parallel between learned / wicked as adjectives (two syllables) and learned / wicked as past participles (one syllable). I wonder if there are any further examples.

Comment: Good answer. In case it isn't clear, it's also worth mentioning that the Shakespearean poems in the format we read them today are not written by his own hand. The primary documents were printed and published in conjunction with other people, and modern readers generally encounter texts that have been edited further to make the spelling easier for them to read.