# Where does "wicked" get its /ɪd/ from?

Tags: etymology, adjectives, pronunciation

There are three ways I know to pronounce the *-ed* at the end of an adjective:

1. /t/ as in *cracked*.
2. /d/ as in *lined*.
3. /ɪd/ as in *naked*

I realise *naked* is a special case because, as [etymonline states](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=naked&allowed_in_frame=0), it comes for Old English *nacod*, so the suffix isn't added.

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96804/3559) shows the pattern of pronunciation of *-ed* in all other cases. However it doesn't explain why [*wicked*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wicked?q=wicked) ends with /ɪd/ (or /id/ or /əd/ depending on the dialect).

[Etymonline says](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=wicked&allowed_in_frame=0) that *wicked* comes from OE *wicca*, so the *d* wasn't already there.

Why do we pronounce *wicked* as /ˈwɪkɪd/ and not /ˈwɪkt/?

Comment: The other *wicked* (something with wicks, like a candle) is pronounced /wɪkt/.

Comment: Also, I would suspect that it gets its /ɪd/ from the same place it gets its /lɪbiːdoʊ/.

Comment: Oh, by the way, the higher likelihood for /ɪ/ in the final syllable (instead of the expected /ə/) in _wicked_ is at least partly a result of echoing the preceding stressed /ɪ/ in /'wɪk/. It's simply easier to leave the tongue in the same position than to move it towards the center; vowəl rədəkʃn is sposta make things easier, not harder. This doesn't explain why there's the extra syllable in the first place, of course; unlike the regular past of _to wick_.

Comment: Wiktionary list of such words: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_with_unexpected_syllabic_-ed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [A Critical Pronouncing Dictionary and Expositor of the English Language](http://books.google.com/books?id=_faiUKL5zRsC), 1839,

> The adjectives *naked, wicked, picked (pointed), booked, crooked, forked, tusked, tressed, and wretched*, **are not derived from verbs, and are therefore pronounced in two syllables**. The same may be observed of *scabbed, crabbed, chubbed, stubbed, shagged, snagged, ragged, scrubbed, dogged, rugged, scragged, hawked, jagged*; to which we may add, the solemn pronunciation of *stiff-necked*; and these when formed into nouns with the addition of *ness*, preserved the *ed* in a distinct syllable, as *wickedness, scabbedness, raggedness*, [&c.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/&c.)

This explanation is reaffirmed in the book, [Teaching Pronunciation: A Reference for Teachers of English to Speakers of Other Languages](http://books.google.com/books?id=twC-H4a8VcYC), 1996,

> Whether they function as verbs or adjectives, most English words ending in the *-ed* suffix follow the same phonological rules as the paste tense inflectional ending (e.g., *striped `/t/`, forked `/t/`, cultured `/d/`, used `/d/`, moneyed `/d/`, furrowed `/d/`, good-natured `/d/`, gray-haired `/d/`, blue-eyed `/d/`*). There are, however, historically based differences in pronunciation between certain formed ending in *-ed*, depending on whether they function as adjectives or verbs. The *-ed* adjectives in this category have **an extra syllable** and take the `/ɪd/` pronunciation, whereas the verbs simply take `/t/` or `/d/`, following the rules for the regular past tense and regular past participle outlined earlier:
>
> [Table with examples comparing the pronunciation of verb forms of words such as *blessed, beloved, learned, dogged, and legged*, with their adjectival equivalents]
>
> **Sometimes, even when there is an adjective with no corresponding verb, the adjective is still pronounced `/ɪd/` (*naked, wretched, rugged, wicked*).**

Comment: I still keep thinking of *learnèd*.

Comment: 21st-century update: _picked, booked, forked, tusked,_ and _tressed_ are now pronounced with the regular /-t/ allomorph. ([Recent research](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4405), however, has shown that peevers and pedants may continue to epenthesize them until they die.) On the other hand, _naked, wicked, crooked,_ and _wretched_ are still two syllables. And, by no coincidence whatsoever, much more common as well.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/32292/8019

Comment: *Naked* used to have a corresponding transitive verb *to nake*, which perhaps is the source of the current pronunciation of the adjective.

Comment: *naked* has three translations in German (no verb though), the adjectives *nackt* and *nackig*, and the rarer *nackend/t* (?) which appears like a participle. Alas, I can't derive from that any useful information for the question, nor is this answer precise enough about the suffix *-ed* to tell if one would be strictly cognate--I'm actually betting on the last one, assuming *-en* as in *golden* + resultative *-t*, cp. *bland, bend*. The verbal form uses *machen* (~make) as auxiliary. *-ig* ~ En. *-y* is, due to the diminutive sound symbolism, rather childish, anyway intimate, i.e. *naky naky*.

Comment: [cont.] [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/nackt) (in German) relates a to-suffix (that is Proto-Indo-European), distinct from that in Latin *nudus*, *sees* *nackend, nackent*, Middle Low German *nakend* as regional variant, has no good explanation (because of lack in comparanda?) and assumes a dental infix, under influence of *nacken* (apparently a verb). Personally, given uncertain status of Kluge's Law, I'd expect so-called expressive lengthening according to older accounts, whereas the itterative nH-suffix plays a role in others, at the latest since Kroonen. Indeed, cp *wiccan*.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's my two-cents worth.

(1) There are actually three ways of pronouncing the *-ed* endings: /ɪd/ (near-close front vowel, commonly occurring in urban U.S. dialects), /əd/ (unstressed mid-central vowel, commonly occurring in rural North Midland dialects), and /ed/ (mid-vowel sound, now rare in America but still prominent in many British dialects).

*Wicked* is pronounced with two syllables because it refers to an animate thing (usually human). Thus it is like *legged* (a two-legged beast), *hanged* (a hanged person), *naked* (a naked person), etc. There are other words which do not belong in this category, as modern English is a very messy language. For example, *wretched*. But note that *wretched* originally applied only to humans and was applied to nonhumans over time.

Back to *wicked*: *wicked* (/wɪkt/) is applied to inanimate things/nonhumans, such as a lamp, just as *legged* (/legd/) is applied to inanimate things/nonhumans, such as a table. Whether the word ends in a /t/ or a /d/ is determined by the position of the tongue just before the final consonant, just like whether we pronounce an /s/ or a /z/ sound in plural forms.

The interesting question for linguists is how *wicked* attained its present form, given that it is derived from a substantive form, not a verbal form—probably by analogy with other adjectival verbs, just like modern American English *snuck* was formed by analogy with *cling, clung, clung*. Originally it was *sneak, sneaked, sneaked*.

There are other words in this category too. /lɜrnd/, as in 'I learned something' v. /'lɜr nɪd/, as in 'a learnèd man'. /bɜnt/, as in 'a bent leg of a chair', v. /'bɜn dɪd/, as in 'a man on bended knee'.

Comment: I always pronounce “hanged” with one syllable, and often pronounce “legged” with one (even in reference to people/animals).

Comment: There is a one-syllable adjective *crooked* (possessing a crook) used for musical instruments. A crook is a removable piece of tubing placed between the mouthpiece and bell of a brass instruments, especially horns. It changes the effective length of the instrument, thereby changing its fundamental pitch.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crook_(music)

Answer (score 0):

If the -ed- goes in the adjective position, the  d/t/id pronounciation does not apply and you pronounce it  as in wicked.
There might be exceptions I suppose.
However, this wine has aged for three years, is different from this is AN AGED WINE

Cheers!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How are they different? They sound the same to me.