# Winged or Wingèd?

Tags: pronunciation

Okay.. here is the problem:

In a certain story I am writing, I have a place called the "Winged Lion Inn" which serves as a locus for several story-related events.

I have a friend that *insists* it should be [pronounced] the "Wingèd Lion Inn" instead, using "learnèd" or "three-leggèd" as examples.

English is a highly flexible language, especially when dealing with matters of pronunciation, so I would like to know if my friend's view is correct.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've only ever seen "winged" as a two-syllable word in poetry, where meter is important.

Comment: @Maroon So should I concede the point to him as "poetic license"?

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder, actually. I've only ever heard "winged angels", for instance, but I wonder if in some situations, a two-syllable pronunciation makes more sense.

Comment: @Maroon It seems "wingèd" remains solely in the hands of poets! =)

Comment: When we use "winged" as a verb to mean "barely struck" we use one syllable: "John got shot in the stomach, but the attacker only winged me."

Comment: @Maroon, seen, but the question is about pronunciation, not about the grave.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not mere poetic licesce.

Words ending in -ed are pronounced /id/ if they serve as adjectives. In case of verbs, the syllable is dropped unless the verb ends in -d or -t

- I learned the truth.
- He was a learnED man
- He crooked a finger for the waitress.
- His teeth were yellow and crookED

Also note `jagged`, `wicked`, `rugged` etc...

This "rule" (like every rule ever) isn't without a few exceptions; **winged** seems to be one of them, according to [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/winged).

PS - 'Beloved' is a semi-exception, in that both pronunciations are acceptable.

Comment: Could this really be the first straightforward answer on this topic to ever exist on the internet?

Comment: @Gio: you're welcome. It might interest you to know that the verbs not pronounce /id/ are pronounced either /d/ or /t/ depending on whether the last consonant is voiced or unvoiced. Cook_t_, but begg_d_

Comment: Nearly all adjectives ending in "ed" are pronounced the same way as the verb. The exceptions are the ones pronounced differently (including *learned, naked, wicked, crooked, ragged, rugged, dogged*). [See this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97037/where-does-wicked-get-its-ɪd-from).

Comment: @PeterShor: Thanks. The answer and Mr. Lawler's comments were very informative.

Answer (score 5):

There are no hard rules for the pronunciation of adjectives/participles on *-ed*. Normally, they are all pronounced *-d/t*, like *striped*, except those ending on *-ted and -ded*. But there are many exceptions pronounced as *-id*, like *naked*. The exceptions are almost all adjectives, or participles used as adjectives: true verbal participles are almost always pronounced the standard way, as *-d/t*.

Then there are words that can be pronounced either way, such as **wingid/wingd**, according to the Oxford English Dictionary (2nd ed.). Note that, when *winged* means "shot in the wing", it is always pronounced *wingd*, according to the same dictionary.

Comment: Does anyone else pronounce "striped" with two syllables? Wondering if it's a regional thing. I grew up in rural Maine.

Comment: @user400166 no, it's all mushed into one for me.  Maybe you could share a sound recording?